# How to remove Pie Charts from Google Maps API V3 on this example?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

This maps adds two pie charts in London and Paris after you zoom in on it.
What I am trying to implement is how could I erase back the pie charts I have added when I zoom out back to level 7 zoom. What do you suggest to me change on this code ? I've already looked into various examples and tried some options without success...
Thanks for your help !

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://code.google.com//apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.10&sensor=false&.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?.js"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load( 'visualization', '1', { packages:['corechart'] });

        ChartMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;

        ChartMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
            $( this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget ).append( this.$div );
        };

        ChartMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {
            this.$div.remove();
        };

        ChartMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
            var marker = this;
            var projection = this.getProjection();
            var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel( this.get('position') );

            this.$div.css({
                left: position.x,
                top: position.y,
                display: 'block'
            })

            this.$inner
                    .html( '<img src="' + this.get('image') + '"/>' )
                    .click( function( event ) {
                        var events = marker.get('events');
                        events && events.click( event );
                    });

            this.chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( this.$inner[0] );

            this.chart.draw( this.get('chartData'), this.get('chartOptions') );



        };


        function ChartMarker( options ) {
            this.setValues( options );
            this.$inner = $('<div>').css({
                position: 'relative',
                left: '-50%', top: '-50%',
                width: options.width,
                height: options.height,
                fontSize: '1px',
                lineHeight: '1px',
                padding: '2px',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                opacity: 0.8,
                //pieHole: 0.4,
                cursor: 'default'
            });
            this.$div = $('<div>')
                    .append( this.$inner )
                    .css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        display: 'none'
                    });





        };

        var cluster_marker = [];
        var map;


        function initialize() {

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.30,00.70)

            var zoom; 
            var markers = [
                ['LONDON',51.30,00.70,50,40,21,40,56], 
                ['PARIS',48.52,2.19,34,56,04,23,57]   
                ];

            var mapOptions = {
                center: latLng,
                zoom: 7,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };

             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                    mapOptions);

          function create() { 

           zoom = map.getZoom(); 

           if (zoom > 7) { 



            for(var k=0;k<markers.length;k++){


                var city = markers[k][0]
                var location = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[k][1],markers[k][2])
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    [ 'Color', 'Quantity' ],
                    [ 'Blue', markers[k][3] ],
                    [ 'Red', markers[k][4] ],
                    [ 'Yellow',markers[k][5] ],
                    [ 'Green', markers[k][6] ],
                    [ 'Purple', markers[k][7] ]
                ]);



                var options = {
                    fontSize: 8,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    legend: {position: 'none'}
                };

                var marker = new ChartMarker({
                    map: map,
                    position: location,
                    width: '250px',
                    height: '100px',
                    chartData: data,
                    chartOptions: options

                });

                //cluster_marker.push(marker);

            }
           } 
          }

         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', create);


        };



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>
<body >
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1800px; height: 1000px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load( 'visualization', '1', { packages:['corechart'] });
    ChartMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;

    ChartMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
        $( this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget ).append( this.$div );
    };

    ChartMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {
        this.$div.remove();
    };

    ChartMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
        var marker = this;
        var projection = this.getProjection();
        var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel( this.get('position') );

        this.$div.css({
            left: position.x,
            top: position.y,
            display: 'block'
        })

        this.$inner
                .html( '<img src="' + this.get('image') + '"/>' )
                .click( function( event ) {
                    var events = marker.get('events');
                    events && events.click( event );
                });

        this.chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( this.$inner[0] );

        this.chart.draw( this.get('chartData'), this.get('chartOptions') );
    };


    function ChartMarker( options ) {
        this.setValues( options );
        this.$inner = $('<div>').css({
            position: 'relative',
            left: '-50%', top: '-50%',
            width: options.width,
            height: options.height,
            fontSize: '1px',
            lineHeight: '1px',
            padding: '2px',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            opacity: 0.8,
            //pieHole: 0.4,
            cursor: 'default'
        });

        this.$div = $('<div>')
            .append( this.$inner )
            .css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none'
        });
    };

    var map;


    function initialize() {
        var cluster_marker = [];
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.30,0.70)
        var zoom; 
        var markers = [
            ['LONDON',51.30,0.70,50,40,21,40,56], 
            ['PARIS',48.52,2.19,34,56,04,23,57]   
        ];

        var mapOptions = {
            center: latLng,
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        function create() { 

           zoom = map.getZoom(); 

            if (zoom > 7) { 
                for(var k=0;k<markers.length;k++){
                    var city = markers[k][0]
                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[k][1],markers[k][2])
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        [ 'Color', 'Quantity' ],
                        [ 'Blue', markers[k][3] ],
                        [ 'Red', markers[k][4] ],
                        [ 'Yellow',markers[k][5] ],
                        [ 'Green', markers[k][6] ],
                        [ 'Purple', markers[k][7] ]
                    ]);
                    var options = {
                        fontSize: 8,
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        legend: {position: 'none'}
                    };
                    var marker = new ChartMarker({
                        map: map,
                        position: location,
                        width: '250px',
                        height: '100px',
                        chartData: data,
                        chartOptions: options

                    });
                    cluster_marker.push(marker);
                }
            }
        }

        function remove() {
            if (zoom <= 7) { 
                for(var i=0; i<cluster_marker.length; i++) {
                    cluster_marker[i].onRemove();
                }
            }
        }

         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', create);
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', remove);
    };

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

What I've done:

- Put cluster_marker inside the initialize function
- Adding markers to cluster_marker array in the loop of create() function:
- Created remove() function
- Put second listener on 'zoom changing' event